# how to write jQuery ajax's success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am getting started to learn jQuery (web development in general) and in this example, I am supposed to send the input (username and password using submit button) to php page using .ajax and success function.

this is the html (form) code:

```
<form id="form1">
    Enter Username :
    <input type="text" id="userName">
    <br>
    Enter Password:
    <input type="password" id="passWord">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sub">
    <br>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

this the jQuery code (the 3 alerts just to check where does my code stops going and the 3rd alert never reached):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").submit(function(){
            alert('clicked');
            var send = $(this).serialize();
            alert('gotData');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login.php",
                data: send,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg){
                    alert('inAjax');
                    $("#result").html(msg.name + " " + msg.pass);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }); 
    });
```

this is my php code:

```
<?php

$name = $_REQUEST['userName'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['passWord'];

$list = array('name' => $name, 'pass' => $pass);
$c = json_encode($list);
echo $c;

?>
```

The code doesn't work (nothing appears on the webpage)

Comment: What browser are you using?  We need to track what's going on.  There's no magic here -- we must take a step-by-step approach to find the problem.  I see you've placed alerts -- good.  You need to look at what's coming back from the Ajax request -- the network tab in the Chrome inspector is a good place to start.

Comment: you should be better off with `console.log()`, than with `alert()`

Comment: great advice in above comments; also - hasn't `success` been replaced with `done` in JQuery recently?

Comment: The problem lies in your form. Use `name`s instead of `id`s for the control elements in order to get the form properly serialized.

Comment: @J.D.Pace I am using chrome, I will look for the network tab in chrome

Comment: @AlexKarshin, thank you my frind, I will look for it

Comment: @MichaelJagroep I don't think so, cause it's working now thanks to Teemu's advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, form elements need to have `name` attributes. `id` values don't matter for submission purposes.

You're better off just using the `.post()` method:

```
$.post('login.php', $(this).serialize(), function(resp){ alert(resp); });
```

Rather than track it with alerts, if you use Chrome, just put `debugger;` at the beginning of your function so it will pause the code and open the inspector for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if you are sending the request in a http enviroment. In order to do that, you can use the [PHP built-in webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) as a quick solution.

```
//Choose the directory
$ cd ~/public_html
//Start the webserver on port 8000
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

Also change the `type` property to `method` instead.

And if there's a problem on the server side check your request using the browser devtools or another http client like Postman.

Comment: Yes but as the jQuery docs says : `You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0`

Comment: Fine but why would OP need to change to `method`? The `type` property has been around since the beginning of jQuery and is not likely to be deprecated any time soon

Comment: OP = Original Post(er)

Comment: It's okay ! I think it makes the code more readable. (Just my opinion)